# Add extra text at the end of the all the links in a certain class

Tags: javascript, php

I have created an 'a' element with class "fragment". I am looking for PHP/JS code, which adds some extra text at the end of all the URL's inside class fragment.

For example:

```
<a class="fragment" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

**The above code should automatically change to**

```
<a class="fragment" href="http://google.com/extratext" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work at all. The link when clicked still leads to the original URL

```
$("a").click(function() {
$(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href") + "extratext");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet appends the href attribute if the link on click:

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.href += "extratext";
});
```

```html
<a class="link" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

If you want to prevent multiple adding use this one:

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if(this.hasExecuted) return; 
     this.href += "extratext";
     this.hasExecuted = true; 
});
```

```html
<a class="link" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

If you want to prevent multiple adding to the url, but add it too all links:

```js
NodeList.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, handler) {
    for(var node of this)
        node.addEventListener(type, handler);
}

HTMLCollection.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, handler) {
    for(var node of this)
        node.addEventListener(type, handler);
}
var hasExecuted = false;       
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
links.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if(hasExecuted) return; 
     for(var link of links)
         link.href += "extratext";
     hasExecuted = true; 
});
```

```html
<a class="link" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
<a class="link" href="http://http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">click here too</a>
```

If you do not want to change the actual href attribute of the link do this instead:

```js
       
 document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.href = this.href + "extratext";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}, false);
```

```html
<a class="link" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

The script as an easy to use function:

```js
  openWithAppendedUrl(document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0], "sometext");

function openWithAppendedUrl(link, urlPart) {
    link.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.href = this.href + urlPart;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Comment: It worked, but I have more than 1 link with class "fragment". It adds the extra text just to the top link and not to the other links with class 'fragment'.

Also when I click the link more than once, it again add "extratext"

Comment: It worked much better now. But still there is one problem. 
When I click on first link, it goes to : http://www.google.com/extratext , which is what I wanted.

But when I click on second link, it goes to: http://www.google.com/extratextextratext

Comment: @user6176114 in which snippet

Comment: 3rd snippet - "If you want to prevent multiple adding to the url, but add it too all links:"

Comment: @user6176114 fixed it

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you!
No, I don't need jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**attr** return your a tag attribute.

```
$("a").click(function() {
   $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href") + "extratext"));
});
```

See here to know more.
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  
  //
  // get all elements with that class
  //
  var fragments = document.getElementsByClassName('fragment');
  
  //
  // for each element attach the event handler
  //
  for(var i = 0; i<fragments.length; i++) {
    fragments[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      
      // add extra text
      var href = this.getAttribute('href');
      this.setAttribute('href', href + 'extratext');
      
      console.log(this.outerHTML);
    }, false);
  }
});
```

```html
<a class="fragment" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **attr** property to get current **anchor** tag **href**.

```js
$("a").click(function () {
  $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "extratext");
});
```

```html
<a class="fragment" href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can find the href of the element you want, after that you can set a new value of its href attribute, which replaces the old one, like this:

```
 <a class="fragment" href="http://stackoverflow/" target="_blank" onclick="addExtraText()">click here</a>

    function addExtraText() {
     var linkElement = document.getElementsByClassName("fragment")[0];
     linkElement.setAttribute('href', 'http://stackoverflow/questions/');
   }
```