# Script not working on mobile

Tags: javascript

So I needed a script that add some extra text at the end of the URL when it is clicked, if it's under 'fragment' class. The problem is it works perfectly fine on the desktop, but it's not working on mobile.

When the banner is clicked, it should lead to http://www.google.com/extratext.

It works fine on desktop but when I click this banner on my mobile, it leads to the original link i.e. http://www.google.com

Here's the code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
NodeList.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, handler) {
    for(var node of this)
        node.addEventListener(type, handler);
}

HTMLCollection.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, handler) {
    for(var node of this)
        node.addEventListener(type, handler);
}
var hasExecuted = false;       
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("fragment");
links.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if(hasExecuted) return; 
     for(var link of links)
         link.href += "extratext";
     hasExecuted = true; 
});
</script>
```

```css
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 18px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fragment:focus, .fragment:hover, .fragment:visited {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.styleraise { 
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline;
} 

.styleraise1 { 
   float: right;
 font-weight: bold;
background-color: #2bde73;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
 color: white;
 font-size:14px;
        padding :1px 6px 1px 6px;
}

.textpara {
    color:grey;
   line-height: 150%;
padding-top: 5px;
}
.imgbor {
border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  Height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a class="fragment" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
    <div>
    <img class="imgbor" src ="https://image.winudf.com/1775/0248f14fdedd6064/icon=150x.png" alt="some description"/> 
    <span class="styleraise">MagicCamera</span><span class="styleraise1">It's free</span>
    <div class="textpara">
        MagicCamera can take photos of different style, with a flashlight function.</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: That just means your event handler isn't being bound. Extending the prototype of built-in things is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am new to coding, someone on Stackoverflow created this script for me. Can you please suggest any alternate way of accomplishing this?

Comment: `someone on Stackoverflow created this script for me` and this is why SO should not be used as code writing service

Comment: I assume you mean over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917601/add-extra-text-at-the-end-of-the-all-the-links-in-a-certain-class)? Well, in any case, wouldn't it be easier to just add that text to begin with in the HTML? And if not, have some JavaScript that runs at the start of the page being loaded and puts the text there? The reason I say the code you have is bad is because `NodeList` can be a live collection that changes over time, so looping over them one to try and bind events won't necessarily work.